# Отслеживание одного касания при нажатии на несколько UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть несколько view на которые добавлены `UITapGestureRecognizer`, если я одновременно нажму на несколько `view`, то отработают несколько жестов одновременно, можно ли как-то выполнить только одно нажатие, а остальные пропустить?

На данный момент я отслеживаю количество нажатий в методе `touchesBegan` и если нажатий больше одного, то я не выполняю методы в `UITapGestureRecognizer`, но такой вариант мне не подходит.

Comment: Попробуйте UIView.appearance().isExclusiveTouch = true

Comment: @OlegSoloviev спасибо, то что нужно!